# SQL Server Instance Recovery?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Can anyone tell me how does the instance recovery happens in sql server when the instance has crashed?

Does it use boot page information for instance recovery?

And during recovery how the before images and after images are recreated?